# How to solve "IndexError: tuple index out of range"?

Tags: python-2.7, postgresql-9.1, openerp-7, indexoutofrangeexception

I have this sql statement that aim to sum sum column of table:

```
p_id   p_name     atc_code         tax_amt   base_amt    date
2300  |A student |WC158 - EWT 1%  |133.93   |13392.86   |2015-07-01
2300  |A student |WC158 - EWT 1%  |62.50    |6250.00    |2015-07-01
901   |B student |WC158 - EWT 1%  |8.31     |830.58     |2015-06-09
2831  |C student |WC160 - EWT 2%  |2736.84  |136842.11  |2015-06-04
905   |D student |WC158 - EWT 1%  |31.25    |3125.00    |2015-06-16
905   |D student |WC158 - EWT 1%  |31.25    |3125.00    |2015-06-29
905   |D student |WC158 - EWT 1%  |31.25    |3125.00    |2015-06-29
905   |D student |WC158 - EWT 1%  |26.79    |2678.57    |2015-06-16
959   |G student |WC158 - EWT 1%  |114.29   |11428.57   |2015-01-10
959   |G student |WC158 - EWT 1%  |478.90   |47890.18   |2015-01-20
2424  |L student |WC158 - EWT 1%  |45.54    |4553.58    |2015-03-03
```

I also have this statement.

```
...
cr.execute('''insert into student_resource_report_line(partner_id,seq,base_amount,tax_amount,percent,atc_code,nature,create_date,write_date)
        select es.partner_id as partner_id,
            (case when es.name like '%WC158%' then 1
                when es.name like '%WC160%' then 2
                when es.name like '%WC010%' then 3
                when es.name like '%WC140%' then 4
                else 0 end) as seq,
            sum(es.base_amt) as base_amount,
            sum(es.tax_amt) as tax_amount,
            (case when es.name like '%EWT 1%%' then '1.00'
                when es.name like '%EWT 2%%' then '2.00'
                when es.name like '%EWT 3%%' then '3.00'
                when es.name like '%EWT 4%%' then '4.00'
                when es.name like '%EWT 5%%' then '5.00'
                when es.name like '%EWT 6%%' then '6.00'
                when es.name like '%EWT 7%%' then '7.00'
                when es.name like '%EWT 8%%' then '8.00'
                when es.name like '%EWT 9%%' then '9.00'
                when es.name like '%EWT 10%%' then '10.00'
                else null end) as percent,
            (case when es.name like '%WC158%' then 'WC158'
                when es.name like '%WC160%' then 'WC160'
                when es.name like '%WC010%' then 'WC010'
                when es.name like '%WC140%' then 'WC140'
                else null end) as atc_code,
            (case when es.name like '%WC158%' then 'NOTEBOOK'
                when es.name like '%WC160%' then 'BACKPACK'
                when es.name like '%WC010%' then 'COLOR'
                when es.name like '%WC140%' then 'BOOKS' else null end) as nature,
            (now()) as create_date,(now()) as write_date
        from ewt_source es where es.date between ? and ? 
        group by es.partner_id,es.name''',(ewt.date_from,ewt.date_to))
```

where **ewt.date_from** and **ewt.date_to** is an input from user. What I can't understand is during execution (when this method is called on my view) it produce an error saying: "IndexError: tuple index out of range". This is what i always saw in my log and it also said that my query is bad.

```
group by es.partner_id,es.name''',(ewt.date_from,ewt.date_to))
File "/opt/openerp/server-7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 161, in wrapper
       return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/openerp/server-7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
   res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Does anyone can point it out where did I committed a mistake? It really spin my head.

Answer (score 1):

I got this frustrating error. 
So the following could be the problems with the query:-

1)when you have `like` your statement make sure there are 2 percentage signs
i.e `like %%WC158%%` so this translates to `%WC158%` when it is being executed

2) for example you have

```
es.date between ? and ? 
                    group by es.partner_id,es.name'''
```

in your code try using `%s` instead of `?`

3)There is this part in your code

```
''',(ewt.date_from,ewt.date_to))'''
```

make sure you have an extra comma at the end

```
,(ewt.date_from,ewt.date_to,))
```

> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", "bar")    # WRONG
>
> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar"))  # WRONG
>
> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar",)) # correct
>
> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ["bar"])  # correct

[source](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html?highlight=insert)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your '?' with '%s' which is used in openerp sql-s as well.

And maybe try to format your SQL into something like that:

```
cr.execute('SELECT id FROM account_move_line \
           WHERE state = %s \
           AND company_id in (%s) \
           ORDER BY id DESC ',\
           ('valid', company_ids))
```

or possibly:

```
self.cr.execute("SELECT sum(debit-credit) " \
                "FROM account_move_line AS l " \
                "JOIN account_move am ON (am.id = l.move_id)" \
                "WHERE l.account_id IN %s" \
                "AND am.state IN %s",
                ( tuple(self.account_ids), tuple(move_state), ))
```

Hope it helps mate!

Answer (score 0):

Remove **?** sign from query instead use **%s** and at last remove `,` and replace it with **%(ewt.date_from,ewt.date_to))**

in short query looks like,

```
qry = "select * from table where field1 = %s and field2=%s" %(value1, value2)
cr.execute(qry)
```